# Php Form submit if else statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a button that switches my data when it is clicked. When the page loads, i want it to load all of the "New" items. The "New" are loaded when the page loads, but when i submit my form to get "used" or "outdated", it still tacks on the "new" items. I am new to php. Thanks!

```
 <form action='' method='POST'>
            <input type='submit' name='New' value="New"/>
            <input type='submit' name='Used' value="Used"/>
            <input type='submit' name='Outdated' value="Outdated" />
          </form>
```

Here is the php.

```
    if(isset($_POST['New'])){
        $sql = "SELECT name FROM table_all_items WHERE name LIKE '%New%' ";
        include '/../includes/product-layout.php';
        }

    if(isset($_POST['Used'])){
        $sql = "SELECT name FROM table_all_items WHERE name LIKE '%Used%' ";
        include '/../includes/product-layout.php';
        }

    if(isset($_POST['Outdated'])){
        $sql = "SELECT name FROM table_all_items WHERE name LIKE '%Outdated%' ";
        include '/../includes/product-layout.php';
        }

    else {
        $sql = "SELECT name FROM table_all_items WHERE name LIKE '%New%' ";
        include '/../includes/product-layout.php';
        }
```

Comment: when you submit the form ALL of the `New`, `Used` and `Outdated` values will be in the `$_POST` array so ALL of the conditions will prove to be true... rethink the logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the if-else condition in wrong way you should change all these conditions as:

```
if(isset($_POST['New'])){
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM table_all_items WHERE name LIKE '%New%' ";
    include '/../includes/product-layout.php';
    }

else if(isset($_POST['Used'])){
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM table_all_items WHERE name LIKE '%Used%' ";
    include '/../includes/product-layout.php';
    }

else if(isset($_POST['Outdated'])){
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM table_all_items WHERE name LIKE '%Outdated%' ";
    include '/../includes/product-layout.php';
    }

else {
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM table_all_items WHERE name LIKE '%New%' ";
    include '/../includes/product-layout.php';
    }
```

Try this now only one condition will work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same name and test the different value

in you html page

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
        <input type='submit' name='my_submit' value="New"/>
        <input type='submit' name='my_submit' value="Used"/>
        <input type='submit' name='my_submit' value="Outdated" />
</form>
```

and server side

```
if($_POST['my_submit'] =='New'){
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM table_all_items WHERE name LIKE '%New%' ";
    include '/../includes/product-layout.php';
    }

if( $_POST['my_submit'] == 'Used'){
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM table_all_items WHERE name LIKE '%Used%' ";
    include '/../includes/product-layout.php';
    }

if( $_POST['my_submit'] == 'Outdated'){
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM table_all_items WHERE name LIKE '%Outdated%' ";
    include '/../includes/product-layout.php';
    }

else {
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM table_all_items WHERE name LIKE '%New%' ";
    include '/../includes/product-layout.php';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible approach to avoid the problem of multiple condtions being true as was happening

```
<form method='POST'>
    <input type='button' name='New' value="New"/>
    <input type='button' name='Used' value="Used"/>
    <input type='button' name='Outdated' value="Outdated" />
    <input type='hidden' id='action' />
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var col=document.querySelectorAll('form > input[type="button"]');
    if( col )for( var n in col )if( col[n].nodeType==1 )col[n].addEventListener('click',function(e){
        document.getElementById( 'action' ).value=this.value;
        this.parentNode.submit();
    }.bind( col[n] ),false);
</script>

if( isset( $_POST['action'] ) ){
    $term=filter_input( FILTER_POST, 'action', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $sql="select `name` from `table_all` where `name` like '%{$term}%';";
    if( in_array($term,array('New','Used','Outdated') ) ){
        include '/../includes/product-layout.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: I realise, too late, that I was mistaken - I thought all values from the submit buttons would be in the POST array but, certainly in chrome, that is not the case.